# No declaration matches in C++

Tags: c++, oop

I'm practicing OOP with C++ and when I try to inherit from a superclass to a subclass, I'm getting an error "No Declaration Matches ...".

```
class RentVehicle{
    protected:
        string brand, model, color;
        int model_yr, no_days;
        float starting_km, ending_km;
    public:
        void recordData();
        void DisplayData();
        float calRent();
        void displayRent(float);

};

class Car:protected RentVehicle{
    protected:

    public:
        string body_type;
        void setData();
};
```

and I'm getting the error here saying * No declaration matches 'void Car::recordData()' *

```
void Car::recordData(){
    fstream car;
    car.open("RentData.txt", ios::app);
    car<<setw(10)<<brand<<setw(10)<<model<<setw(10)<<body_type<<setw(10)<<color<<setw(10)<<model_yr<<setw(10)<<no_days<<setw(10)<<kms<<endl;
    car.close();
}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: If you want `Car` to have its own `recordData` then you need to declare that in the class definition. Otherwise, there ain't no such member function as `Car::recordData()` (it's inherited from the base class and must be defined as a base class function)

Comment: OOP begins when you override a virtual function. Perhaps you want `recordData` to be one?

Comment: probably, the question is why `recordData` is not *automatically* defined in the namespace of the derived class `Car`. It seems like a natural thing to do. Otherwise, what's the point of duplicating exactly the same definition twice, in the base and the derived classes?

Answer (score 4):

`Car` does not have a method called `recordData`, this is `RentVehicle`'s method:

```
void RentVehicle::recordData(){

// ...
```

However, `RentVehicle` does not have a `body_type` member, that's the subclass's member, so you won't be able to assign to it here.

So perhaps you should declare `recordData` in `Car`'s class definition, in the first place.

Comment: I'll try, Thank you.